# Unable to select checkbox using Selenium webdrive (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been puzzling at this for a few hours now. Checked through similar issues on Stackoverflow but been unable to find a solution.

I have a checkbox I'm trying to use Selenium webdriver to check, but when I run the script, I don't get any error messages but the checkbox remains unchecked.

I'm using the line below to select and check the box

```
IWebElement checkBox = m_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/label/span"));
checkBox.Click();
```

I've copied the HTML from it below.

```
<div class="input-group single-option label-empty" >
    <label class="" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="true"  required  />
            <span>I have read and understood the <a data-toggle="#privacy-terms" 
                  data-group="privacy-terms">Privacy Policy</a> and <a data-toggle=
                  "#terms" data-group="privacy-terms">Terms and Conditions</a>. </span>
    </label>
```

I'd really be grateful for some help. I'm pretty new to automation...and `C#`

Unfortunately, I am unable to post the url as it's a passworded client site. If I can post the HTML, that may help...

I've posted the html from the page in question but removed the client name :)

[Link to HTML](https://pastebin.com/2ZjcNshQ)

If I select the checkbox through `Chrome` developer tools and copy the `Xpath`, I get this.

```
IWebElement checkBox = m_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section/form/div[2]/label/input"));
```

I re-ran it and `Selenium` generated an error.

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Element
>    is not
>   clickable at point (491, 593). Other element would receive the click:
>   ...   (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.45.615291
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)

[developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xewo.jpg)

Here is a screenshot of developer tools with the checkbox ticked. Could it be something to do with the 'span'?

Comment: this XPATH: "//div[2]/label/span" is not a robust one... can't you find a better one?

Comment: also it will help if you can add the url if you can...

Comment: `"//input[@type='checkbox'][@name='privacy']"` try this xpath

Comment: And btw, try to avoid absolute xpath, use it when you do not have any other option.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The error was generated again.

Comment: Yay! figured it out. Instead of using "checkBox.Click()", I used "checkBox.SendKeys(Keys.Space) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking the `SPAN` not the `INPUT` that is the checkbox. This should work.

```
m_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='privacy']")).Click();
```

You may need a wait, depending on what is going on before the click.

Your error about element is not clickable could be any number of things. It could be popup blocking it, a floating DIV panel, a loading spinner, ... etc. You will need to deal with the popup (by closing it, etc.), floating DIV may require the page to be scrolled, or for the spinner a wait for the spinner to become invisible. It's hard to say without more information.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of using "checkBox.Click();", I used "checkBox.SendKeys(Keys.Space);

and it works. Now I'm trying to do the same with the recaptcha which by definition should be difficult.